# to specify a certain paragraph with a vertical line to which adhered an English letter

Tags: paragraphs

My question seems to be chalenging!!! How can I specify a paragraph with a vertical line in the close of that? For example, below picture contains a shape includes two paragraph. The first paragraph is specified by a vertical line to which an English letter (A) adhered.
[image]

Comment: You can see the `leftbar` environment from the `framed` package.

Comment: thank you so much it works for me. But do you know how adhere a letter